# In Linux, what do all the values in the "top" command mean?

Tags: linux, command-line, top-command

When you run `top` and see all running processes, I've always wanted to know just what everything actually means.  e.g. all the various single-letter state codes for a running process (R = Running, S = Sleeping, etc...)

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) says what the state codes are mapped to, but not what they actually mean. From the `top` man page:

```
'D' = uninterruptible sleep
'R' = running
'S' = sleeping
'T' = traced or stopped
'Z' = zombie
```

'R' is the easiest; the process is ready to run, and will run whenever its turn to use the CPU comes.

'S' and 'D' are two sleep states, where the process is waiting for something to happen. The difference is that 'S' can be interrupted by a signal, while 'D' cannot (it is usually seen when the process is waiting for the disk).

'T' is a state where the process is stopped, usually via `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP`. It can also be stopped by a debugger (`ptrace`). When you see that state, it usually is because you used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd> to put a command on the background.

'Z' is a state where the process is dead (it has finished its execution), and the only thing left is the structure describing it on the kernel. It is waiting for its parent process to retrieve its exit code, and not much more. After its parent process is finished with it, it will disappear.

Comment: This doesn't say what causes an `S` state. In contrast, I know that disk activity can cause a `D` state.

Comment: @A-B-B: that's because there are many things which can cause an `S` state. The most common one is when the process is waiting for an event and/or timeout (`select`/`poll`/`epoll`, blocking `read` from the terminal or network, and many others).

Comment: Related answer with more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process/224042#224042

Comment: Is there a modern update available to this answer? I see processes with state code 'I' - and the man page doesn't say what that is!

Comment: If it's stopped by a debugger, isn't the state `t`, not `T`?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the command [`man top`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) to look up the states:

```
D = uninterruptible sleep
I = idle
R = running
S = sleeping
T = stopped by job control signal
t = stopped by debugger during trace
Z = zombie
```

Comment: Hey dude! You stole my answer!

Comment: RTFM is not a valid answer here, since the manual alone is insufficient to determine what the status really means.

Comment: `[~] # man top
sh: man: command not found`
I know, I know: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html

Answer (score 9):

Programs like `top` and `ps` takes these values from the kernel itself. You can find its definitions in the source code here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3950e975431bc914f7e81b8f2a2dbdf2064acb0f/fs/proc/array.c#L129-L143

```c
static const char * const task_state_array[] = {

    /* states in TASK_REPORT: */
    "R (running)",      /* 0x00 */
    "S (sleeping)",     /* 0x01 */
    "D (disk sleep)",   /* 0x02 */
    "T (stopped)",      /* 0x04 */
    "t (tracing stop)", /* 0x08 */
    "X (dead)",     /* 0x10 */
    "Z (zombie)",       /* 0x20 */
    "P (parked)",       /* 0x40 */

    /* states beyond TASK_REPORT: */
    "I (idle)",     /* 0x80 */
};
```

For more info see this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462098/79648