# Is there some cases in which SIGKILL will not work?

Tags: linux, signals, sigkill

Are there any cases where an application running on Linux, which has not blocked signal `SIGKILL`, will not get killed on firing `SIGKILL` signal?

Comment: On Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work

Answer (score 13):

`SIGKILL` cannot be blocked or ignored (`SIGSTOP` can't either).

A process can become unresponsive to the signal if it is blocked "inside" a system call (waiting on I/O is one example - waiting on I/O on a failed NFS filesystem that is hard-mounted without the `intr` option for example).

(Another side case is zombie processes, but they're not really processes at that point.)

Comment: Does that mean when an user application makes a system call it blocks all the signals till that system call returns ?

Comment: It is not "blocked", it's in the "uninterruptible sleep (D)" state. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767551/how-to-stop-uninterruptible-process-on-linux

Comment: @Mandar, no. you can't "block all the signal". The D state is something internal to kernel (e.g. Reading from CD-ROM, syncing to disk etc..)

Comment: What you're describing is called "Disk Sleep", indicated by a "D" in the process status.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, when the process is blocked in kernel space, e.g. reading on a blocked NFS file system, or on a device which does not respond.

Answer (score 5):

Check with `ps a` (or you can use other flags as well) the process state.
If a process state is

```
D : uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
```

then you cannot kill that process.
As others mentioned, and as it is defined, this is usually caused by a stuck I/O, for example process waiting to do I/O to a disconnected NFS file system.

Comment: The SIGKILL signal will still be pending and if somehow the system gets unstuck on that process it will automatically handle it (exiting the process) upon return to userspace.