# cifs mount cause processes to enter uninterruptible sleep

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, mount, cifs

Given CentOS 6.3 box (2.6.32).

I compile sources in the Linux. The source tree is located on Windows 7 box, which is CIFS mounted.

Everything was ok, till recently compilation time started to grow to some unreasonble times (e.g. several minutes to link a separate file).

I notices processes involved in compilation (make, gcc, ld) enter uninterruptible sleep state ('D' state in top).

Any ideas wht is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem with processes entering uninterruptible sleep when writing many files to a CIFS mounted SMB share.

There are some good explanations of uninterruptible processes on the question "[What is an uninterruptible process?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process)

I was able to resolve the issue by using [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) to manage the CIFS mounts rather than using fstab.

> autofs is a program for automatically mounting directories on an
>   as-needed basis. Auto-mounts are mounted only as they are accessed,
>   and are unmounted after a period of inactivity. Because of this,
>   automounting NFS/Samba shares conserves bandwidth and offers better
>   overall performance compared to static mounts via fstab.