# How to kill postgres processes that won't die?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following processes running per `ps aux | grep postgres`

> postgres         8720   0.0  0.0  2492848   5652   ??  SN    2:33PM
>   0:00.04
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker
>   -s mdworker -c MDSImporterWorker -m com.apple.mdworker.shared postgres          495   0.0  0.0  2514428   1776   ??  S     1:57PM   0:00.07
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdflagwriter
>   postgres          491   0.0  1.0  2669764 166180   ??  Ss    1:57PM
>   0:10.31 com.apple.IconServicesAgent postgres          490   0.0  0.0 
>   2505832   2884   ??  Ss    1:57PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/xpcd postgres
>   485   0.0  0.0  2514284   1284   ??  S     1:57PM   0:00.07
>   /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent postgres          484   0.0  0.0  2536788
>   1708   ??  S     1:57PM   0:00.06 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent postgres
>   479   0.0  0.0  2508256   1100   ??  Ss    1:57PM   0:00.06
>   /sbin/launchd postgres          427   0.0  0.0  2493792    608   ?? 
>   Ss    1:55PM   0:00.02 postgres: stats collector process     postgres 
>   426   0.0  0.0  2654624   2208   ??  Ss    1:55PM   0:00.02 postgres:
>   autovacuum launcher process     postgres          425   0.0  0.0 
>   2646300    764   ??  Ss    1:55PM   0:00.03 postgres: wal writer
>   process     postgres          424   0.0  0.0  2638108   1608   ??  Ss 
>   1:55PM   0:00.07 postgres: writer process     postgres          423
>   0.0  0.0  2638108    836   ??  Ss    1:55PM   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process     postgres          419   0.0  0.0  2493792
>   500   ??  Ss    1:55PM   0:00.00 postgres: logger process     postgres
>   85   0.0  0.1  2638108  13844   ??  Ss    1:55PM   0:00.04
>   /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data
>   Username       8910   0.0  0.0  2432784    612 s003  R+    2:35PM
>   0:00.00 grep postgres

I want them dead!

But killall postgres gives me:

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I understand I need to use:

```
kill -INT `head -1 /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid`
```

But I do not understand this command.

Guidance is appreciated. Long frustrating morning!

Comment: Have you tried `kill -9 8720` (where `8720` is the PID)? Note that this may result in data loss since the OS will kill the process in a very unkind manner.

Comment: Cool. I'll post a more detailed answer.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy And now it doesn't work. So weird.

Comment: I added a couple extra notes to my answer, which might explain why it isn't working sometimes. See if they help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, you can use the `kill` command to stop running processes. More specifically, `kill` sends signals to processes. The most basic kill command is something like this:

`kill <pid>`

This sends the `SIGTERM` signal to the process, telling them to stop.

Occasionally, you'll have a process that is really stuck, and doesn't seem to respond to SIGTERM. In this case, you can tell the `kill` command to do it a little (or, you know, a lot) more forcefully by doing:

`kill -9 <pid>` or, equivalently, `kill -KILL <pid>`

This sends the `SIGKILL` signal to the process, the effect of which is (very generally) that the OS immediately takes the process out of the run queue, and stops it. **This can, in general, be somewhat dangerious, since it does not give the program the change to "clean up" or finish running in any kind of a reasonable way. It just literally stops it immediately.**

You can find more information about `kill` on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)), or in the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) (`man kill` on your local machine). The command is fairly standard across Linux, UNIX, BSD, and OS X, so the documentation should more or less apply to any of these.

Additionally, you can find more information about what the different signals are intended to do on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(computing)) as well.

As an added bonus, I find that [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fow7iUaKrq4) has prevented me from ever forgetting about how this command works.

**EDIT**: Sometimes, there are processes that just *cannot be killed*. One of the most common situations in which this occurs is when the process is in the `D` state (see the `STAT` column in the output of `ps axu`). This state means that the process is uninterruptible, commonly because it's waiting for some I/O operation to finish that never will for various reasons. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423521/process-perminantly-stuck-on-d-state).

Another note: sometimes killing a process doesn't work because you need to kill the **parent process**, not some worker process it's `fork`'ed. You can see the process "heirarchy" (i.e., the parent/child relationships) using the command `ps axjf`. You can see more information about the `ps` command in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) (`man ps` on your local machine). As with `kill`, the `ps` command is quite standard, so documentation should mostly apply to all of the various UNIX-like OS'es.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547434/how-to-nicely-stop-all-postgres-processes) solved the problem for me.

**Kill all processes named 'postgres'**

```
pkill postgres
```

Comment: doesn't work.  `jim     9813  0.0  0.0  22564   944 pts/1    S+   15:09   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres`

Comment: @mLstudent33 - from the print out of your comment, you have run the command `ps | grep postgres`. As you can see in your print out the words `grep` and `postgres` are there, this is because you have returned the very process you just ran. Better to use `ps | pgrep postgres`.

tl;dr - it does work!

Comment: No matter how many times I use this command, the psotgres processes are gererated again.