# What is the difference between TASK_KILLABLE and TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

It seems like TASK_KILLABLE should be a subset of TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, since killing a task is one way of, um, interrupting it; however, according to sched.h [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L202) and [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L223) it looks like TASK_KILLABLE is **UN**INTERRUPTIBLE.

```
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE      1
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    2
#define TASK_WAKEKILL           128
#define TASK_KILLABLE           (TASK_WAKEKILL | TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)
```

What this really comes down to for me is; when would I want to use [wait_for_completion_interruptible_timeout](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/completion.c#L208) versus [wait_for_completion_killable_timeout](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/completion.c#L246)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, a little more searching answered this for me: the [article](http://lwn.net/Articles/288056/) referenced in [this somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223727/1669250) states:

> Kernel code which uses interruptible sleeps must always check to see whether it woke up as a result of a signal, and, if so, clean up whatever it was doing and return -EINTR back to user space. The user-space side, too, must realize that a system call was interrupted and respond accordingly; not all user-space programmers are known for their diligence in this regard.

and

> many of these concerns about application bugs do not really apply if the application is about to be killed anyway. It does not matter if the developer thought about the possibility of an interrupted system call if said system call is doomed to never return to user space. So Matthew created a new sleeping state, called TASK_KILLABLE; it behaves like TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE with the exception that fatal signals will interrupt the sleep