# Does the linux system call read(fd, buf, count) return less than count when fd is a regular file?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

When we call `read(fd, buf, count)` on Linux, can the return value of the system (function) call be less than count other than the scenario where there were fewer bytes to the end-of-file?

I looked it up in the man page, it says

"On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position  is  advanced  by  this
       number.   It  is  not  an  error  if  this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example
       because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are  reading
       from a pipe, or from a terminal), **or because `read()` was interrupted by a signal**."

So here is my question:
How can `read()` on a regular file be interrupted by a signal? By what possible signals?

Comment: it should not read `open(fd, buf, count) `... :-)

Comment: implement signal handler for SIGINT and then send SIGINT

Comment: You might send `SIGINT` to some soft-mounted NFS file read.

Comment: Note that this is a more interesting question if you consider small values of count verses large values.

Comment: Even if a particular kernel did guarantee that it wouldn't return less data, why would you make that assumption? The `read()` function gives you the number of bytes returned. Use it. When a function returns a value or a possible error code, code as if it might return anything. Don't assume anything.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `read()` can be interrupted by a signal. But not when the process is reading from a descriptor that belongs to file on file system.

When process calls `read()` on file it enters a so-called **uninterruptible sleep**. In this mode process will not handle any signals until system call is completed. Either because of some error or when requested data was read.

**Note**: when process is in an uninterruptible sleep you can't even terminate it with SIGKILL signal. Or in the other words `kill $pid -9` will have no effect.

*In this question there is an explanation of an uninterruptible sleep:*
[What is an uninterruptable process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process)

***Note further***: there is and interesting real-life cases when hard drive experiences failure and all processes that either trying to write data to that disk (File System) or to read from it are stuck and cannot be killed by any means other than rebooting a system. This is also true for volumes mounted over a network, such as NFS.

**Edit:** as *psmears* has pointed out, `read()` can be interrupted if reading from file that is on the volume, mounted via NFS *iff* `intr` mount option was specified.

Comment: This is wrong: there are cases where a `read()` on a filesystem file *can* be interrupted. The classic example is an NFS mount mounted with the `intr` option.

Comment: @psmears, please, read documentation more carefully: `intr — Allows NFS requests to be interrupted if the server goes down or cannot be reached`. This means that OS (driver) will not wait indefinitely. This is not the same as sending some signal to a process reading/writing from a file from a mounted volume will result in syscall being interrupted.

Comment: No, you read the documentation more carefully ;-) `soft` means the driver will time out. `intr` (depending on kernel version) allows the user to interrupt (signal) the process. From the docs: "If intr is specified, system calls return EINTR if an in-progress NFS operation is interrupted by a signal. "

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) specifies which calls can be interrupted by a signal, and `read()` is on the list. You have to enable this behavior in Linux (with `SA_RESTART`), it's not on by default.