# Can not kill process by kill -9?

Tags: linux

I try to kill process by using command "kill -9 pid", but can not succeed. Anybody know how could I kill such process and why I can't kill it ?

Comment: A `kill -9` always succeeds, _if you have permission to control that process_. So most likely you do _not_ have permission to control this specific process. You might want to take a look at the `sudo` utility for this. It allows you to raise your privilege level for the kill command.

Comment: @arkascha Ever had a process in an uninterruptable sleep (`D`)?

Comment: @arkascha actually I start the process, so I think I should have permission to kill it.

Comment: @glglgl What does uninterruptable sleep mean ? The process is a scala code, do you mean it is the sleep in java/scala api ?

Comment: @arkascha `kill -9` can fail if there is an uninterruptable system call in progress. This can be caused by driver limitations or by bugs (kernel or driver) while processing a system call.

Comment: @zjffdu Maybe that process changed permissions? A typical thing for daemons getting started for example. Or maybe you started the process with raised privileges yourself? Just take a look into the process table: who owns the process?

Answer (score 1):

The process could be zombie? Its good to check process state using ps command as well if you have permission.

Answer (score 1):

If your process is in an [uninterruptable sleep (`D`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28system_call%29#Uninterruptible_sleep) due to hanging in some hardware access, you indeed cannot terminate that process.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223644/296974) is another explanation.

Personally, I saw such `D` states for example when accessing files on a SD card or USB stick when there was a hardware problem. But there are many other scenarios where such a state might occur.