# Read blocks indefinitely on external SSD

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm trying to read data from a faulty external SSD to create an image for data recovery. The drive is an Apacer Panther SSD connected to a USB port via an ICY BOX SATA to USB connector on Ubuntu.

Executing the MWE below, `read` hangs at some address. The address is mostly stable between consecutive runs, but it can vary (e.g. on different days). With a block size of 1, `read` hangs on the first byte of  some sector. The result is that the program freezes and no signal interrupts the read, ctrl-c simply prints "^C" to the terminal but does not kill the program and the alarm's handler is never called.

Closing the terminal and re-running the program on a new terminal, no `read` is completed (it hangs on the first iteration). Only by disconnecting and reconnecting the SSD can I read again from the disk. However, if I disconnect the drive while `read` is blocked, the program continues.

Modifying and running the program with stdin as the file descriptor, both SIGINT and SIGALRM interrupt `read`.

So the question is:
a) Why does `read` block indefinitely since according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) it is interrupted by signals?
b) Is there any way to fix this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sig_handler(int signum){
    printf("Alarm handler\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Register ALARM signal handler to prevent read() from blocking indefinitely
    struct sigaction alarm_int_handler = {.sa_handler=sig_handler};
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &alarm_int_handler, 0);
    
    char* disk_name = "/dev/sdb";
    const int block_size = 512;
    int offset = 0;
    
    char block[block_size];

    // Open disk to read as binary file via file descriptor
    int fd = open(disk_name, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1){
        perror(disk_name);
        exit(0);
    }

    int i;
    int position = offset;

    for (i=0; i<100000; i++){

        // Reset alarm to 1 sec (to interrupt blocked read)
        alarm(1);

        // Seek to current position
        int seek_pos = lseek(fd, position, SEEK_SET);
        if (seek_pos == -1){
            perror("Seek");
        }

        printf("Reading... ");
        fflush(stdout);
        int len = read(fd, block, block_size);
        printf("Read %d chars at %d\n", len, position);

        if (len == -1){
            if (errno != EINTR){
                perror("Read");
            }
            else {
                printf("Read aborted due to interrupt\n");
                // TODO: handle it
            }
        }

        position += len;
        
    }

    close(fd);

    printf("Position %d (%d)\n", position, i * block_size);
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output on the terminal looks like this

```
.
.
.
Reading... Read 1 chars at 29642749
Reading... Read 1 chars at 29642750
Reading... Read 1 chars at 29642751
Reading...
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is an excellent tool for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What happens if you increase the block size to something like 512 or 4096 or so? Reading one byte at a time will not increase chances of data recovery, because data is transmitted from SSD to RAM in larger blocks anyway. It will just slow things down to a crawl because you need a billion of system calls to read a single gigabyte of data.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I did not know ddrescue, I'll sure check it out. But I did use dd at first (not reinventing the wheel logic) and it also hang at similar addresses

Comment: @Fritz Of course I'm not trying to create the image with a block size of 1. This is just to take a finer-grain look into what happens. Larger block sizes produce the same results (of course we can't talk about "first sector byte" in these cases though).

Comment: I've had to do such recovery before. I wrote a custom program that would read a disk and retry a bad block a few thousand times. The program would do any kind of device reset if needed. Then, after the ordeal was complete (and I had my data back), I heard about [as pmacfarlane mentioned]: `ddrescue` Note that `ddrescue` is _not_ just a simple `dd` clone. It has massive amounts of retry/recovery logic in it (e.g. IIRC, it reads sectors/tracks in forward and reverse order, etc.).

Comment: If a controller/card is freezing up, you may want to get a special board that can selectively reset/power-cycle the locked up H/W when your program detects the lockup. Either the flash memory, usb adapter, or SATA-to-usb. I assume the adapter has separate power from an AC source (i.e. it does _not_ just depend upon power from the USB cable on your PC). Or, if you have a desktop PC lying around [or score one on e-bay], you may want to plug the SSD directly into a SATA disk adapter card (i.e. bypassing the SATA-to-USB step entirely).

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like your SSD might be defective (fails to respond to a request, e.g. its firmware hangs while trying to recover from corrupt data in flash memory) or the kernel driver has a bug.

As to why the process does not respond to signals: There is a process state called ["uninterruptible sleep"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptible-process) (abbreviated as state `D` in `top` and `htop`). Processes go into this state when their control flow is inside the kernel (i.e. during a system call like `read`), for example waiting for data from a disk or network (NFS mounts are infamous for this during a network outage). If your SSD does not reply to a data request, then the process would wait for data indefinitely, since the kernel will not ask the SSD a second time. Or maybe it does, and the SSD always refuses to answer, or might even time out after a few hours of trying... who knows.

Comment: With htop on a different terminal, the program does indeed go into the D state when it hangs.

Comment: @AlexP Well, that settles it then, i guess. If the device never recovers, then there is no way other than skipping the address ranges that are known make the SSD hang. If I remember correctly, `ddrescue` has such a feature, i.e. reading a list or problematic sectors from a file, or similar.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a kernel driver bug.

Did you try non-blocking reads? Regular files cannot be polled, but the descriptor can still be made non-blocking

Comment: I am using non-blocking reads, since I open the file with the O_NONBLOCK flag

Comment: Do we really expect a bug in the kernel driver if we have a generic SSD in use? An unnumbered amount of devices is in the market and running quite fine with linux. So why OP should find such a reproducible bug by simply reading a single block? That will happen by every access from the uper file system layers also...